# How to find the unit cell for the superlattice of twisted bilayer graphene?

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics

I was trying to write a code where I generate the coordinates of twisted bilayer graphene, then  finding the matching points between the two layers, to obtain the resultant moire pattern. But something is not working in my code and it's not giving me the solution that I need. I can't spot the error here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby 
import math

d0 = 0.3330630630630631 # interlayer distance
a0 = 0.15469469469469468 # distance between the two basis atoms of graphene

theta = 15*np.pi/180 # the twist angle between both layers in degree

nmax = 10 

# lattice vectors sublattice 1
a1= np.array([3/2*a0,3**0.5/2*a0,0])
a2= np.array([3/2*a0,-3**0.5/2*a0,0])

# lattice vectors sublattice 2
b1 = np.array([ np.cos(theta) * a1[0] - np.sin(theta) * a1[1], np.sin(theta) * a1[0] + np.cos(theta) * a1[1], 0. ])
b2 = np.array([ np.cos(theta) * a2[0] - np.sin(theta) * a2[1], np.sin(theta) * a2[0] + np.cos(theta) * a2[1], 0. ])


#Coordinates sublattice 1 & 2 for layers 1 & 2
coords1a = np.array([i * a1 + j * a2 for i in range(-nmax,nmax+1) for j in range(-nmax,nmax+1)])
coords1b = np.array([i * a1 + j * a2 + [a0,0.,0.] for i in range(-nmax, nmax+1) for j in range(-nmax, nmax+1)])


coords2a = np.array([i * b1 + j * b2 + [0.,0.,d0] for i in range(-nmax,nmax+1) for j in range(-nmax,nmax+1)])
coords2b = np.array([i * b1 + j * b2 + [np.cos(theta)*a0, np.sin(theta)*a0,d0] for i in range(-nmax,nmax+1) for j in range(-nmax,nmax+1)])

coords1 = np.concatenate((coords1a, coords1b), axis=0)
coords2 = np.concatenate((coords2a, coords2b), axis=0)


# to find the matching coordinates of the two layers that are supposed to form the moire pattern

for a in range(len(coords1)):
    for b in range(len(coords2)):

        dis1 = coords1[a][0] - coords2[b][0]
        dis2 = coords1[a][1] - coords2[b][1]
        distance1 = np.sqrt(coords1[a][0]**2 + coords1[a][1]**2)
        distance2 = np.sqrt(coords2[b][0]**2 + coords2[b][1]**2)
        if abs(dis1) < small_variable:
            if abs(dis2) < small_variable:
                if distance1 == distance2: 
                    matching_coords.append(coords1[a])
                    print(coords1[a], ' is matching with ', coords2[b])
```

I tried changing the vectors and using different values of the small variable but nothing worked so far.

Comment: What exactly is your *programming* question? What you have written in the title is a *physics* question. See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/